# Are $\forall(a,b) \in{A \times{B}}$ and $\forall a\in{A},\forall b\in{B}$ logically equivalent?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Here is my proof attempt:

Observe that $\forall{a\in{A},\forall{b\in{B}}} \equiv \forall{a,b}(a\in{A} \wedge b\in{B})$ and $\forall{(a,b)\in{A\times{B}}} \equiv \forall{a,b}((a,b)\in{A\times{B}})$. We show that $\forall{a,b}(a\in{A} \wedge b\in{B} \Leftrightarrow (a,b)\in{A\times{B}})$. Let $a\in{A} \wedge b\in{B}$, by definition of cartesian product $a\in{A} \wedge b\in{B} \Leftrightarrow (a,b)\in{A\times{B}}$, as desired.

The questions I arrived are the following:

1. Did I use the logic correctly?
2. If my proof is correct, how can I improve it?
3. If they are logically equivalent, which one is more elegant to use in mathematics research?

Comment: Those aren’t formulas so it doesn’t really make sense until you stick something like $P(a,b)$ at the end with $P$ a predicate. Your quantification also aren’t strictly sensible either in the sense of first-order logic (which wouldn’t matter in a less strict setting, but you are asking about a technical logical point).

Comment: Generally holds $[(\forall x)(R \land S)] \Leftrightarrow [(\forall x)R \land (\forall x)S]$ and if/when you mean this, then your equivalence is true, but it somehow strangely recorded and, imho, needs improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a notation in a paper, for example $$\forall a \in A: \forall b \in B: P(a,b)\tag{1}$$ is semantically the same as $$\forall (a,b) \in A \times B: P(a,b)\tag{2}$$

so in that sense is does not matter and they are eqeuivalent. But realise that $A \times B$ is a set theory notion, and that $(1)$ is the more "purely logic way" of formulating it. So I'd only use $(2)$ if $A \times B$ were also some object of interest in the context. I wouldn't introduce that set, if it were extraneous or just to express the formula with one quantor or some such reason.

Comment: I didn't think about the fact that the cartesian product is an operation from set theory so it makes sense that wouldn't be appropiate in all settings. Thanks for your answer!